# Boostrat collapse solo me muestra una iteración de un NgFor

Tags: angular, bootstrap, ngfor, collapse

Estoy intentando crear un collapse div de un ngfor con boostrap collapse y no logro hacer que se me muestren todos los documentos de mi colección. La iteración está dentro de un ngFor y el button que me hace el collapse está fuera del ngFor. "existeSubtareas" es un boolean que le mando su valor true si existe una respuesta truthy de BD y falsy si no existe en BD

Este es el array de objetos que me llega por BD:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6172ee268df3d5a15d827313",
        "nombre": "Subtarea 1",
        "descripcion": "Descripcion Subtarea Front",
        "actividad": "6172ee068df3d5a15d8272e4",
        "createdAt": "2021-10-22T17:00:22.637Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-11-09T16:18:33.943Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "responsable": {
            "_id": "5c7efab2ec50e8eb1a2f3e30",
            "nombre": "MORENO AGUIRRE JORGE LUIS"
        },
        "estado": "FINISHED"
    },
    {
        "_id": "6172ee6d8df3d5a15d827315",
        "nombre": "Subtarea 2",
        "descripcion": "Descripcion Subtarea Front",
        "actividad": "6172ee068df3d5a15d8272e4",
        "createdAt": "2021-10-22T17:01:33.904Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-10-22T17:01:33.904Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

En el front solo se muestra el primer objeto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté ponerles id's únicos y no creo que esa sea la solución

El código de mi página es (por motivos de dinamismo reduzco mi código):

```
<html>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" mat-icon-button matTooltip="Ver subtareas" matTooltipPosition="above"
          data-target="#subtasks" data-toggle="collapse" style="right:4px">
          <span class="material-icons-outlined">splitscreen</span>
          <strong>Ver subtareas</strong>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="subtasks" *ngIf="!existeSubtareas" class="collapse">
      <span><strong>¡No hay ninguna subtarea por mostrar!</strong></span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="existeSubtareas" class="subtask_container">
      <div id="subtasks" class="collapse subtarea._id" *ngFor="let subtarea of subtareas; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="form-group__label"><strong>Subtareas: </strong></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="form-group__label">Nombre subtarea: </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input *ngIf="estaEditando" type="text" placeholder="Coloque un nombre" class="input"
              style="border:0px; background-color: transparent; width: 100%;" id="subtask_edit_name"
              [(ngModel)]="subtarea.nombre" name="nombre_subtarea + {{subtarea._id}}">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="form-group__label">Descripción: </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input *ngIf="estaEditando" type="text" placeholder="Coloque una descripcion" class="input"
              style="border:0px; background-color: transparent; width: 100%;" id="subtask_edit_desc"
              [(ngModel)]="subtarea.descripcion" name="descripcion_subtarea + {{subtarea._id}}">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue poner el id y el class en un div fuera del ngFor.

Supongo que se debe a la renderización y tiempos de ejecución de Angular, si alguien puede proveer una explicación exacta estaría muy agradecido

```
  <div  id="subtasks" *ngIf="existeSubtareas" class="collapse">
          <div class="subtask_container" *ngFor="let subtarea of subtareas; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">
```